# Vlookup from Another Workbook with fill to Last Row

Tags: string, vba, excel, vlookup

I'm looking to import data from another file (combinedWorkbook) to my master file (the file which is running the code) using a vlookup. I then need it to drag the vlookup down to the bottom row of data (using column M in the masterfile as a reference to when the data ends) with cell I15 being the starting point for the vlookup in the masterfile.

The problem I'm having is that when running the macro the vlookup is happening in cell M10 in my masterfile, not dragging down the vlookup to the end of the data and not referencing the combinedWorkbook.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I got so far

```
Dim combinedBook As Workbook
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim combinedFilename As String
Dim combinedWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook

MsgBox ("Select Unpaid Capital Extract")

Set targetWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
caption = "Please Select an input file"
combinedFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

Set combinedWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(combinedFilename)

ThisWorkbook.Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-8],combinedWorbookSheet1!R1C1:R700000C2,2,0)"
Range("M16").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Range("I15:I60297").Select
Range("I60297").Activate
Selection.FillDown
Range("I15").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Range("I15").Select

combinedWorkbook.Close False
```

Comment: This looks wrong...combinedWorbookSheet1  not only because of the missing k but also how you are joining Workbook with Sheet.

Comment: 8 Columns back from M is E.  This whole section makes no sense to me:  I then need it to drag the vlookup down to the bottom row of data (using column M in the masterfile as a reference to when the data ends) with cell I15 being the starting point for the vlookup in the masterfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are simply too many unknowns in your code to give a specific answer.

Some observations:

1) Always use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code, it will pick up mistakes and inconsistencies for you.

2) Watch out for unused variables declared in your code

3) Always specify which workbook and worksheet you are working with; don't just put `Range` ... or `Cells`.... this leads to all sorts of bugs.

4) Your `VLOOKUP` syntax for working with another workbook needs to be of the order

```
'[" & combinedWorkbook.Name & "]Sheet1'
```

5) xlsx are not text files btw re: your filter

6) For the rest i.e. where you want formulas to go, how you are determining last row etc I am just having to guess. Be specific when coding and try bullet pointing pseudo code first so you are clear what is going on at each stage.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

    Dim filter As String
    Dim caption As String
    Dim combinedFilename As String
    Dim combinedWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook

    MsgBox "Select Unpaid Capital Extract"

    Set targetWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

    filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
    caption = "Please Select an input file"
    combinedFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

    Set combinedWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(combinedFilename)

    'Assuming M is used to find last row in targetWorkbook
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'this wasn't specified (specify appropriate sheet name)

        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

         'Assuming I is where formula is being put
        .Range("I15:I" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = _
                           "=VLOOKUP(RC[-8],'[" & combinedWorkbook.Name & "]Sheet1'!R1C1:R700000C2,2,0)"

        combinedWorkbook.Close False

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That works like an absolute dream. Thank you for the tips as well, I will keep them in mind going forward - all good learning.

Comment: Lol. Not a problem. You can also upvote helpful answers by clicking the up pointing triangle but you need x number of rep point for that and I am not sure how many that is.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you need to apply a vlookup formula in your master file gathering data from another workbook.

The proper strucutre is as followed:
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(**RC[8]**,[Book1]Sheet1!**R1C5:R23C6**,2,FALSE)"

The first bold text is the place of the value you are looking for, relative to the active cell.

The second bold text is the position of your reference table in your other workbook ( here it is book 1).

You can apply this formula to your masterfile by using a loop.

```
Dim lastRow as Integer
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
endCount = 15 + lastRow
For i = 15 to endCount
ActiveSheet.Cells(i,13).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-8],[combinedWorkbook]Sheet1!R1C1:R700000C2,2,FALSE)"
next i
```

This will apply the vlookup formula in the column I starting row 15 searching for the value in the same row but 8 column before (column "A") and will apply for as many row as there are value in the column M.